# Is phosphoric acid to be considered a hazardous waste?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I've found some English sites proclaiming phosphoric acid to be used for porcelain cleaning and e.g. clogged drains, even though I mainly bought it to use to clean coffee makers and water kettles.

In my country (Finland) phosphoric acid can be found from the list of hazardous waste. However, there are contradictory views regarding whether phosphoric acid can be poured in to the sewer or not. If it's a hazardous waste, then it shouldn't. But I have this English resources saying that it can.

Should I abide by the local rules saying that it's a hazardous waste or is there a reason to believe it can be used safely e.g. in clogged drains or for cleaning the toilet?

Comment: Or you could pour it onto your garden as it is an essential element ( phosphorus) for plants. I pour TSP ( tri sodium phosphate ) in my garden ; my soil is too acidic to use phosphoric acid.

Answer (score 3):

Phosphoric acid is a "food" additive because its acidity prevents the growth of microorganisms.  By itself it can cause burns, and high levels of phosphate in the diet have been linked to weaker bones (greater risk of fractures).

If you pour it down the drain, its acidity should not be the issue.  You could neutralize it with baking soda, and it will tend to become neutralized and buffered in nature on its own, but I think the primary issue is that it will yield phosphate ions which act as a fertilizer/nutrient source for algae growth and can cause algal blooms in ponds and streams that can dominate the ecosystem and choke out plant and animal diversity.

For that reason, don't pour it down the drain even though it will likely become neutralized as it acts on the clog.

If you just need to manage it, neutralize it with baking soda, and boil off the water, or let it evaporate to yield sodium phospate salt.  We don't want the sodium phosphate to enter directly into the local watershed, but you could put it on houseplants.  I don't know if phosphate fertilizer is allowed where you live, but if it is, you could put it on your lawn.  It PROBABLY would also be OK to dispose of the solid Sodium Phosphate in the trash.

Comment: I think, it depends to a strong extent what the wastewater treatment plant does to the water; i.e. if it constantly monitors phosphate to precipitate it or not.

Comment: I know that In some cases, wastewater goes straight to a septic lagoon or sea without any treatment.